# Attachment Id of emails in java

Tags: java, api, email, attachment

I am currently working with java mail api . I need to list the attachment details also wants remove the attachment from some emails and forward it to others. So i'm trying to find out the Attachment ID. How can i do it? Any suggestion will be appreciate!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
private void getAttachments(Part p, File inputFolder, List<String> fileNames) throws Exception{
    String disp = p.getDisposition();
    if (!p.isMimeType("multipart/*") ) {
        if (disp == null || (disp != null && (disp.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT) || disp.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.INLINE)))) {             
            String fileName = p.getFileName();
            File opFile =  new File(inputFolder, fileName);
            ((MimeBodyPart) p).saveFile(opFile);
            fileNames.add(fileName);                    
            }
        }
    }else{
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
        int count = mp.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){                 
            getAttachments(mp.getBodyPart(i),inputFolder, fileNames);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There ain't anything as an *attachment ID*. What your mail client displays as a message with attached contents, is really a MIME Multipart and looks like this ([sample source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526560%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)):

```
From: John Doe <example@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="XXXXboundary text"

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain

this is the body text

--XXXXboundary text 
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"

this is the attachment text

--XXXXboundary text--
```

Important things to note:

1. Every part in a multipart has a `Content-Type`
2. Optionally, there can be a `Content-Disposition` [header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387)
3. Single parts can be themselves multipart

Note that there is indeed a `Content-ID` header, but I don't think it's what you are looking for: for example, it is used in `multipart/related` messages to embed `image/*`s and text from a `text/html` in the same email message. You have to understand how it works and if it's used in your input.

I think your best option is to examine the `Content-Disposition` and the `Content-Type` header. The rest is guesswork, and without actual requirement one can't help with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Apache Commons Email package](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email/1.5/jar) which has a `MimeMessageParser` class. With the parser you can get the content id (which could be used to identify the attachment) and attachments from the email message like so:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawEmail.getBytes());
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, is);
MimeMessageParser parser = new MimeMessageParser(message);

// Once you have the parser, get the content ids and attachments:
List<DataSource> attachments = parser.getContentIds.stream
    .map(id -> parser.findAttachmentByCid(id))
    .filter(att -> att != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have created a list here for the sake of brevity, but instead, you could create a map with the `contentId` as the key and the `DataSource` as the value.

Take a look at some more examples for using the parser in java [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser), or some code I wrote for a scala project [here](https://github.com/onema/LambdaMailer/blob/feature-attachments/src/main/scala/io/onema/forwarder/ForwarderLogic.scala#L136-L141).